# How To Get Maximum Of A Table Column In Yii2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

i want to get maximum of price from table laptop in yii2.
how can i do that?

i used below code

```html
<?
Laptop::find()->max('price')
?>
```

but it seems not working :(

how can i access this data.

and in other type i coded before like below

```html
<?

$min=Laptop::find()->select('min(price)');


?>
```

but it s not working again ..

how to add this query ??

Comment: the first sintax seems correct what do you mean with  "seems not working" ?   .. please explain better

Comment: when i use it not working :(

Comment: the sintax seems correct but  You have errors? ... you have wrong result? .. you have no resutl? .. explain where and how you are using the the function

Comment: Missing argument 1 for yii\db\Query::max(), called in ..

Comment: I hav posted  an answer  let me now

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tecnically you don't need  an Active Recordefor get the max or min result  you could try using active Query

```
$max = (new \yii\db\Query())
->from('laptop_table')
    ->max('price');

echo $max;
```

If you have the error

> Missing argument 1 for yii\db\Query::max()

is because you must pass the column name for calculate the max

anyway the code above is equivalent  to

```
  $max = Laptop::find()->max('price');
```

Comment: Might mention that the above $max variable, is of type string

Comment: @FiHoran  in Yii2 the notation for a column name iin a function is the string name  ..  (the content should be number)

Answer (score 0):

Like below :

echo $max_price = Laptop::find()->max("price");

Answer (score 0):

Multi select and max price in the product table with model product:

```
$product = \common\models\Product::find()->where(['status'=> 1])->andWhere(['>','count',0])->max('price');
```